# Django - Cache query results in model methods

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

Suppose this (simplified) setup:

```
class Related(models.Model):
    # ... fields

class Model(models.Model):
    # ... fields
    related_model = models.ForeignKey(Related)

    def a_method(self):
        # ... some instructions
        rel = self.related_set.all()
        # ... some other instructions
```

Now suppose a_method is used in a template in multiple places. I know I can use the "with" tag to cache the results (and the related query) in the template, but is there any way I can have it cached inside the method itself?

I was thinking about setattr'ing a property of the object with the computed queryset and then check inside a_method if the queryset is cached there, but maybe there's a more elegant way.

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you need such behaviour? The solution you mentioned (setting an attribute, perhaps with switch variable re_is_cached) is the way to go. For templates `with` prevents multiple database lookup.

Comment: This is called memoization, and there are plenty of libraries and snippets to do it.

Comment: Yes, memoization. Why didn't I think about that. Thanks.